# Trying to pass an mp3 file as a parameter in React Native and I am getting errors. How can I resolve this problem? I am using Expo-av for reference

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am currently building an app where I want there to be a play button that when pressed plays an audio file. My method of doing so is to create a soundplayer component that creates the button and audio sync so that I can just call the component in the main screen I use it in. I can get the soundplayer component to work just fine when I manually put the mp3 file path in it's proper place, but not when I try to pass it in as a parameter. Take a look at my code below and see if you may be able to help resolve the situation.

SoundPlayer Component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

function SoundPlayer({ mp3 }) {
  const [sound, setSound] = React.useState();

  async function playSound() {
    console.log('Loading Sound');
    const { sound } =  Audio.Sound.createAsync({ mp3 });
    setSound(sound);

    console.log('Playing Sound');
    await sound.playAsync(); }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return sound
      ? () => {
          console.log('Unloading Sound');
          sound.unloadAsync(); }
      : undefined;
  }, [sound]);

  return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
      <Button title="Play Sound" onPress={playSound} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center'
  }
})

export default SoundPlayer
```

App Screen

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <SoundPlayer  mp3 = {require('/Users/viswajithkumar/DharmaWorldwide/Screens/assets/Audio/FrenchTouch.mp3')}/>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Documentation of [expo-av](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/#usage), we can see that there are two different methods for static files and remote files to load.

**For Static Files (require...) this is the way to load a file**

```js
const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(require('./assets/Hello.mp3'));
```

**For Remote Files (https://example.com/test.mp3) this is the way to load a file**

```js
const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync({
  uri: 'https://example.com/test.mp3',
});
```

So replacing,

```js
const { sound } =  Audio.Sound.createAsync({ mp3 });
```

with

```js
const { sound } =  Audio.Sound.createAsync(mp3);
```

Should fix the issue. Just make sure the `location` of the sound file is correct.

---

##### Another Approach

A better way to load and play audio files, which I personally feel the best is to use `useRef` variable for the sound instance. I've created a snack for the implementation [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/audio-player)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was searching all night for an answer to this and now I can move forward with the rest of my project. Cheers! I went ahead and implemented the method you sugessted with the useRef variable. Much easier to work with that way.

Comment: Could you by any chance also show me how to get the music to stop playing at the press of the button?

Comment: @ViswajithKumar Glad I could help. If this answer solved your issue, please consider accepting and upvoting it. Also, for Play/Pause operations look at my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68045661/13170636) answer, and if you feel it works for you, considering upvoting it too.

Comment: Yeah absolutely. It says that I need 15 reputation points to give an upvote (currently have 11), but I'll get 4 more soon and give you the upvote.

Comment: You can still accept the answer. There's a tick mark at the starting of my answer.. Look at [this](https://i.imgur.com/k3FuDCC.jpg) image for reference. By clicking on that tick mark you say that "Yes, this answer has solved my issue". This helps future users to solve their issues. To know more about Accepting and Upvoting, [click here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1073060)