# What is the way to load a file to react native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I tried the following method but cannot import successfully:

[image]

I check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69418545/1904685) but cannot import it.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: @SurajRao thank you for your explanation, I know this but there isn't any code for copy or search. Sees the directory structure and errors. That's enough for this question. Thank you again.